# opening a 32bit visual C# project in 64bit OS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, 32bit-64bit

I've built a project in Micorosft Visual C# in my 32bit windows system , and it works fine there but I need to be able to open my project and do a little bit of my work on my other system which has a 64bit windows. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: It should just work (caveats: on the assumption that it doesn't rely on an x86 only COM library, etc.)

Comment: What issue are you running into? It should work fine.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding , the exe file runs fine in both system , but what I want is to open the visual C# project in my other system and modify some of my codes there.

Comment: Install Visual Studio 2010 on your 64bit Windows and open your project in it. Where's the problem in that?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "32-bit project"

Comment: To open the C# project on your other system, install Visual Studio.  Where is the issue?

Comment: it doesn't open in my 64bit visual C# . and I thought it's because I have wrote the code in my 32bit , so you say it's got nothing to do with converting 32bit to 64bit?

Answer (score 5):

.Net is architecture-independent.
It will work out-of-the-box.

If it uses P/Invoke, you'll need to make sure that you're using `int` and `IntPtr` correctly so that it will work on 64-bit systems too.

If it uses 32-bit-only COM libraries, you'll need to set the Target Platform to `x86` rather than `Any CPU`.

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding , the exe file runs fine in both system , but what I want is to open the visual C# project in my other system and modify some of my codes there

Comment: and I want to know if there's a convertor or something that ables me to open a 32bit visual C# project in my 64bit visual C# .

Comment: There is no such thing as a `32bit project` or `64bit C#`.